# How to check which timeout is being hit in .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am using a custom c# application  (.net 4.8 with IIS 8.5). The application allows me to run a report (against an Oracle DB) and export the report in csv. This particular report is larger and times out at 20 minutes of therabouts. There are some config files which allow timeouts to be increased which i have done. I've also made changes in IIS where i can see timeouts (ie. app pool and asp). I am still hitting the problem however. Can anyone provide me some basic troubleshooting ideas (ie. any tools) which I can look into to confirm exactly what timeout my application is hitting?

thanks
Gary

Comment: What error message do you get? Which reporting system?

Comment: Hi there, the error in the Windows Server 2012 event log is "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out".

Comment: i've also updated web.config and all the timeout settings i can find for the .net app but still get the same error at exactly 20 minutes.

Comment: You need to find and post here the code that is doing the web request causing this System.Net.WebException.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the session in your code then the IIS default session state time out is 20 minutes.
you can change editing web.conifg file:

```
      <sessionState timeout="120" cookieless="AutoDetect">
```

Change the IIS worker process idle timeout value (Default: 20 minutes)

[image]

try to set the execution timeout

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90000" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

[image]